# ASP.NET Logon View Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call on the Logon Form and i receive this error:

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1674: 'method group': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Source Error:

Line 15: 
Line 16: 
Line 17: @using (Html.BeginForm)
Line 18: {
Line 19:

This is my code for my Logon View where the error occurs:

```
@model SimulareRestaurant.Models.LogOnValidator
@{
    Layout = null;
 }

 <h2>Logare</h2>
 <p>
  Please login. @Html.ActionLink("CreateNewAccount","Register") if you dont have one
 </p>



  @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Login Failed. Please correct the possible mistakes")


  @using (Html.BeginForm)
  {

     <div>

     <fieldset >

        <legend>Informatii cont</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumeUtilizator)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumeUtilizator)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NumeUtilizator)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Parolă)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Parolă)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Parolă)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Logare" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Now I have searched the web for the past few days throughly and it is my understanding       that ins some cases, calling the Dispose() method does the trick, but i really dont see the point. This particular error is very hard to find and thats why i decided to make this post. I apolodgise if it is too trivial for you guys, im a newbie in asp and oop in general

Comment: `Html.BeginForm` is a method. You are missing a pair of parenthesis in your `using` block. The correct syntax is `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

you forgot the parenthesis after `BeginForm` method call